# What is the ResearchKit class prefix "ORK" an abbreviation for?

Tags: ios, researchkit

[ResearchKit](http://researchkit.github.io/)'s classes (etc.) use "ORK" as a class prefix: `ORKConsentDocument`, `ORKTaskViewController`, `ORKVisualConsentStep`, etc.

I hypothesize the RK stands for ResearchKit, but what about the O?

I'm looking for an official or authoritative source; no speculative answers please.

Comment: Here's a speculative comment :) Perhaps "Open" since Apple open sourced it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does stand for "Open", but the project is just "ResearchKit". We needed a third letter to reduce the chance of prefix collision when the project is incorporated in peoples' apps.